# Ordering events and retaining earliest and latest timestamp at each location in sequence

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have some data which records some sequential processing events.

Each event occurs at a location (Location) and includes both a begin date (BeginDT) and an end date (EndDT).

Processing at a Location may involve multiple sequential steps each of which is recorded with a BeginDT and EndDT.

A step which is non-final at a location should be recorded as complete (Complete as true (1)).

A step which is final at a location should be recorded with incomplete (Complete as false (0)).

However, it is possible for processing at a location to be incomplete due to some missing or erroneous records.
When processing at a location has a step (or steps) which indicate(s) incomplete but no subsequent final step to indicate complete then the incomplete record (or most recent incomplete record of the sequence at the location) is to be considered the final record.

Processing multiple times at the same location in sequence may occur.
When processing multiple times at the same location in sequence and the leading event at the location is complete then each event is to be considered an entirely separate.

I have included a method which I was trying to use to help determine how each event is to be handled by identifying the previous and next records but I am not sure if that is a useful approach.

The desired final result is the Order, Location, earliest BeginDT, and latest EndDT for each sequential set of processing events at a Location:

```
/*
[Order] Location    BeginDT     EndDT
1       A           2000-01-01  2000-01-06
2       B           2000-01-10  2000-01-11
3       C           2000-01-20  2000-01-21
4       D           2000-01-30  2000-01-31
5       A           2000-02-01  2000-02-02
6       C           2000-02-10  2000-02-11
7       C           2000-02-20  2000-02-21
8       B           2000-03-01  2000-03-02
9       D           2000-03-10  2000-03-11
10      D           2000-03-20  2000-03-23
11      E           2000-03-30  2000-03-31
*/

declare @T table (
ID int identity,
Location varchar(20),
Complete bit,
BeginDT date,
EndDT date
);

insert @T (Location, Complete, BeginDT, EndDT)
values
('A', 0, '2000-01-01', '2000-01-02'),
('A', 0, '2000-01-03', '2000-01-04'),
('A', 1, '2000-01-05', '2000-01-06'),
('B', 1, '2000-01-10', '2000-01-11'),
('C', 1, '2000-01-20', '2000-01-21'),
('D', 0, '2000-01-30', '2000-01-31'),
('A', 1, '2000-02-01', '2000-02-02'),
('C', 1, '2000-02-10', '2000-02-11'),
('C', 1, '2000-02-20', '2000-02-21'),
('B', 1, '2000-03-01', '2000-03-02'),
('D', 1, '2000-03-10', '2000-03-11'),
('D', 0, '2000-03-20', '2000-03-21'),
('D', 1, '2000-03-22', '2000-03-23'),
('E', 1, '2000-03-30', '2000-03-31');

with cte as (
select
    row_number() over (order by BeginDT) as [Order],
    Location,
    Complete,
    BeginDT,
    EndDT
from @T
)
select
*
from cte
order by
[Order],
Complete;

with cte as (
select
    row_number() over (order by BeginDT) as [Order],
    Location,
    Complete,
    BeginDT,
    EndDT
from @T
)
select
    [Order],
    Location,
    BeginDT,
    EndDT,
    Complete,
    max(Previous) as Previous,
    max(cast(PreviousComplete as int)) as PreviousComplete,
    max([Next]) as [Next]
from (
    select
        cte.[Order],
        cte.Location,
        cte.BeginDT,
        cte.EndDT,
        cte.Complete,
        case
            when cte.[Order] = j.[Order] + 1
                then j.Location
                else NULL
            end as Previous,
        case
            when cte.[Order] = j.[Order] + 1
                then j.Complete
                else NULL
            end as PreviousComplete,
        case
            when cte.[Order] = j.[Order] - 1
                then j.Location
                else NULL
            end as [Next]
    from cte
    cross join (
        select
            [Order],
            Location,
            Complete
        from cte
        ) as j
    ) as S
group by
    [Order],
    Location,
    BeginDT,
    EndDT,
    Complete;
```

I developed a solution:

```
with
cte1 as (
    select
        row_number() over (order by BeginDT, EndDT) as [Order],
        Location,
        IsComplete,
        BeginDT,
        EndDT
    from @T
    ),
cte2 as (
    select
        [Order],
        Location,
        case
            when 1 <> 1
                or Location <> Previous
                or Previous is NULL
                or (
                    1 = 1
                    and Location = Previous
                    and PreviousIsComplete = 1
                    )
                then BeginDT
            end as BeginDT,
        case
            when 1 <> 1
                or IsComplete = 1
                or (
                    IsComplete = 0
                    and (
                        1 <> 1
                        or Location <> [Next]
                        or [Next] is NULL
                        )
                    )
                then EndDT
            end as EndDT
    from (
        select
            [Order],
            Location,
            BeginDT,
            EndDT,
            IsComplete,
            max(Previous) as Previous,
            max(cast(PreviousIsComplete as int)) as PreviousIsComplete,
            max([Next]) as [Next]
        from (
            select
                cte1.[Order],
                cte1.Location,
                cte1.BeginDT,
                cte1.EndDT,
                cte1.IsComplete,
                case
                    when cte1.[Order] = cj1.[Order] + 1
                        then cj1.Location
                        else NULL
                    end as Previous,
                case
                    when cte1.[Order] = cj1.[Order] + 1
                        then cj1.IsComplete
                        else NULL
                    end as PreviousIsComplete,
                case
                    when cte1.[Order] = cj1.[Order] - 1
                        then cj1.Location
                        else NULL
                    end as [Next]
            from cte1
            cross join (
                select
                    [Order],
                    Location,
                    IsComplete
                from cte1
                ) as cj1
            ) as T1
        group by
            [Order],
            Location,
            BeginDT,
            EndDT,
            IsComplete
        ) as T2
    ),
cte3 as (
    select
        'Begin' as [Type],
        row_number() over (order by [Order]) as [Order],
        Location,
        min(BeginDT) as DT
    from cte2
    where BeginDT is not NULL
    group by
        [Order],
        Location
    union
    select
        'End' as [Type],
        row_number() over (order by [Order]) as [Order],
        Location,
        min(EndDT) as DT
    from cte2
    where EndDT is not NULL
    group by
        [Order],
        Location
    )
select
    [Order],
    Location,
    [Begin] as BeginDT,
    [End] as EndDT
from (
    select
        [Type],
        [Order],
        Location,
        DT
    from cte3
    ) as T
pivot (
    max(DT) for [Type] in ([Begin], [End])
    ) as pT
order by [Order];
```

I welcome any improvements. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide your expected result set as well.

Comment: The expected result set is enclosed in a comment block preceding the sample code.

Comment: Since this code is working, I'd post on codereview.stackexchange.com instead